# Making sure my rewrite rule is a 301 re-direct

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I have the following re-write rule which directs krmmalik.com to krmmalik.com/me
How do i make sure this rule is a 301 re-direct, and if it isnt one already, how can i turn it into one?

I've tried using the mixing and matching the tips from this site

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

as well as Google's Support Articles and existing SO questions, but not having much luck. Note the re-write rule in itself so far has been working fine.

I've also added a CNAME for "www" to "krmmalik.com" in my DNS file. Is that good enough, or do i need to add a specific 301 redirect for that as well?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?krmmalik.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ me [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /me [L,R=permanent]
```

The `R=permanent` flag instructs a 301 status redirect (and you can use `R=301` if you prefer, but I think that "permanent" is more readable).

Putting a forward-slash at the start of the `/me` target URL will tell Apache to redirect the user to the directory named "me" at the web server's public root directory. So in your case it should redirect the user to krmmalik.com/me (or www.krmmalik.com/me).

Also, you don't need to wrap the match pattern in parentheses, because you don't need to capture the slash for later use. So `^/?$` will do the job fine.

Comment: OK so the krmmalik.com re-direct is now working fine. Thank you.
However, the "www" re-direct is still failing. I didn't quite understand your last instruction and so it's possible that could be the reason it's failing. Note, i have a CNAME setup for "www" that points to krmmalik.com anyhow. Not sure how that affects this or the SEO though.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: To configure your Apache host to force users to www.krmmalik.com take a look at [this ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/446/how-can-i-enforce-that-my-urls-always-start-with-www) which talks about the Apache configuration needed.